# Change active partition of LTO tape

Tags: c, windows, winapi, storage

I've been trying to change the active partition of an LTO8 tape in Windows (7 & Server 2012 R2) using the following code snippet (which gcc compiles without any warnings):

```
DWORD partition= 2;

if(SetTapePosition(hTape, TAPE_LOGICAL_BLOCK, partition, 0, 0, FALSE) != NO_ERROR)
   <irrelevant error code here>
```

which returns without any errors. But it doesn't change the partition. I can use the same function and handle to seek to various blocks within the first (default) partition, so I don't think that's the problem.

The tape is definitely partitioned, and I have no problem changing to the second partition under linux using the mt command.

Comment: regarding: `DWORD partition= 2;`  `gcc` will flag this statement as an error as `gcc` does not know the names for various types of variables (as used in VS)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue is with Quantum's device driver; if I force load HP's device driver, I can change the active partition without any issue.